# Error Connect dynamodb with golang in dockerfile

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

### Return Error in getItem dynamodb

```
FATAL NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain caused by: EnvAccessKeyNotFound: 
failed to find credentials in the environment. SharedCredsLoad: failed to load profile, xxx- 
prod. EC2RoleRequestError: no EC2 instance role found caused by: RequestError: send request 
failed caused by: Get http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/: 
net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

#### package connection dynamodb

```
// connectDynamo returns a dynamoDB client
func ConnectDynamo() (db *dynamodb.DynamoDB) {
    return dynamodb.New(session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region:                        &RegionName,
        MaxRetries:                    aws.Int(1),
        CredentialsChainVerboseErrors: aws.Bool(true),
        HTTPClient:                    &http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second},
    })))
}
```

#### .env Example

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="EXAMPLE123"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="EXAMPLE123/EXAMPLE123"
AWS_REGION="us-east-1"
```

Expect connect and getItem in dynamodb, but not connect return error:
FATAL NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain caused by: EnvAccessKeyNotFound:
failed to find credentials in the environment. SharedCredsLoad: failed to load profile, xxx-
prod. EC2RoleRequestError: no EC2 instance role found caused by: RequestError: send request
failed caused by: Get http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/:
net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Answer (score 0):

The exceptions which is being thrown states that your code is looking for credentials from the EC2 Metadata, not from your `.env` file. Its best practice to use an IAM role, and I would encourage you to do so also.

Follow the link I have shared below, ensuring you allow adequate permissions for your role to access your DynamoDB table.

### EC2 Instance Profile

*Amazon EC2 uses an instance profile as a container for an IAM role. When you create an IAM role using the IAM console, the console creates an instance profile automatically and gives it the same name as the role to which it corresponds. If you use the Amazon EC2 console to launch an instance with an IAM role or to attach an IAM role to an instance, you choose the role based on a list of instance profile names.*

Create an instance profile role for your EC2 instance and it should pick up that role based on the credential providers chain:

[Default Credential Provider Chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html#credentials-default)

[Create Instance Profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile.html)

[Identity and access management in Amazon DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/authentication-and-access-control.html)

Comment: I think understood, 
it would be possible to use in the following format shown in javascript but in golang?

export const conection = AWS.config.update({
  region: process.env.REGION,
  accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
});

Comment: It's possible yes, but it's practice to use the instance profile which you can modify and change with no application deployments. It also means you do not need to set keys anywhere and thus more secure.